# FormGroup and spread operator

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, spread-syntax

I have an error that I don't understand with ReactiveForms.

output var from roomsGroup returns an array of object like I wish.

Then I use spread operator to pass all objects to the form group in roomingGroup. But only the first object is set.

I don't know what I have to do to make it work.

Any idea ?

```
export function roomingGroup (fb: any) {
    return fb.group(
        ...roomsGroup(fb)
    );
}

function roomsGroup (fb) {
    let output = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        let nameOfProperty = 'R' + i;

        output.push({
            [nameOfProperty]: fb.group({
                quantity: fb.group({
                    adult: [''],
                    child: ['']
                })
            })
        })
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Return object instead of array?

Comment: No, return only the first object and not the others : { R1: { ... } } instead of { R1: { ... }, R2: { ... }, ... }

Comment: Nope, I already try it. I think I miss something simple.

Comment: Actually I just want to inject inside fb.group from roomingGroup, the fb.group built in roomsGroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want output object. So I have to work with object :

```
let output = {};

for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    let nameOfProperty = 'R' + (i + 1);

    output = (<any>Object).assign(output, {
        [nameOfProperty]: fb.group({
            quantity: fb.group({
                adult: [''],
                child: ['']
            })
    })})
}

return output;
```

That's my solution.